# Django - Google Drive API how to store and retrieve file using Django

Tags: django, google-drive-api

I have a requirement of uploading and downloading image files in google drive via web application built using Django. I have explored using Django Google Drive Storage API, it seems to be working while saving files. But I have no clue where the files are getting saved and how to read the files. if anyone has experience using Django google drive API or have a recommendation for storing files in google drive would highly be helpful at this moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using models to upload the image files, something like this:

```
class Imageupload(models.Model):
    imagefile= models.ImageField(upload_to='img',blank=True,storage=gd_storage)
```

views.py file looks like:

```
lst=Imageupload.objects.all()
url_for_first_imagefile=lst[0].imagefile.url #used to display or download the image in template
```

Then you  can directly access them using imagefile.url attribute.